# Add attribute and value selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, attributes

I have a source like

```
li id = "li_795" onclick = "return select_size('795')"
```

and I would like to add an argument through selenium python chrome webdriver, so it should be

```
li id="li_795" onclick="return select_size('795')" **class="selected**"     "
```

but I do not understand how to add an attribute and its value. What I tried was: find an element on those HTML lines (for example `driver.find_element_by_id("li_797")`  but then I dont know how to move on, I mean, I dont have nothing of specified, and the `"class="selected"` doesn't even exist - is there a way to do this?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about overwriting the original class:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('li_795').setAttribute('class', 'selected')")
```